# How to install SVN in Eclipse Java EE IDE on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, svn

I just installed Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers on my Ubuntu system. **Is SVN already part of the Eclipse package**?

If **not**,

> How do I **install** SVN from Eclipse - so that I could create a **new project** from files checked out from a **repository**?

Do I need to download and install a subclipse package **from tigris**? Can't I do it **from within Eclipse itself**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do it from within eclipse.
go to 
help->install new software 
and put this url
http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x
in the address field.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go http://subclipse.tigris.org/ . This is the SVN integration project for Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to the answer @Alin has provided, I can note that most Eclipse plug-ins are available by choosing "install new software" option under the help menu.

[Instructions](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess;jsessionid=6A1AECD69EEF363A9C030468939DB753?pageID=p4wYuA)